# GPG Check fails on CentOS Stream 9, but not on Fedora 35

Tags: centos, grafana, fedora, dnf

I am having an issue with a lab server I am running using CentOS 9, when I'm trying to install Grafana, the GPG check fails. This is the output I get:

```
     Importing GPG key 0x24098CB6:
     Userid     : "Grafana <info@grafana.com>"
     Fingerprint: 4E40 DDF6 D76E 284A 4A67 80E4 8C8C 34C5 2409 8CB6
     From       : https://packages.grafana.com/gpg.key
    Is this ok [y/N]: y
    Key import failed (code 2). Failing package is: grafana-8.5.5-1.x86_64
     GPG Keys are configured as: https://packages.grafana.com/gpg.key
    The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
    You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
    Error: GPG check FAILED
```

When I try the same on my local Fedora 35 machine, I get this:

```
    Importing GPG key 0x24098CB6:
     Userid     : "Grafana <info@grafana.com>"
     Fingerprint: 4E40 DDF6 D76E 284A 4A67 80E4 8C8C 34C5 2409 8CB6
     From       : https://packages.grafana.com/gpg.key
    Is this ok [y/N]: y
    Key imported successfully
    Running transaction check
```

The packages being downloaded are the same `grafana-8.5.5-1.x86_64.rpm`, I am using `dnf` for both installations, and the `grafana.repo` files are both the same:

```
[grafana]
name=grafana
baseurl=https://packages.grafana.com/oss/rpm
repo_gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.grafana.com/gpg.key
sslverify=1
sslcacert=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

I know I could just turn off the gpg checking, but I am not comfortable with a solution like that.

Any help resolving this would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if I should supply any more information.

I've quite recently swapped over to CentOS and Fedora, so I apologize if this has been resolved before, but I was unable to find it.

Answer (score 2):

There has been some change with the default crypto policies in CentOS streams 9.

`update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT:SHA1`

The packages need to be re-signed with a SHA256 or SHA521 key instead of SHA1.

Ref: https://access.redhat.com/articles/6846411

Comment: Thank you, worked on AlmaLinux 9. After executing, does the system revert to SHA256 on reboot if system wide encryption policies are set ?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone finds this thread with the same problem installing Plex Media Server on Rocky / RHEL / CentOS Stream 9 the information from @askb solved my issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).